# what is difference between from_unixtime vs from_timestamp

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp, impala

Can someone please help to understand basic difference between date format functions available in Impala.

Just to understand

from_unixtime vs from_timestamp

which one is betetter form_unixtime or from_timestap   when fetching than a million rows .

Answer (score 1):

The Unixtime is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).
The converter on this page converts timestamps in seconds, milliseconds and microseconds to readable dates. E.g.

UNIXTIMESTAMP VALUE:

```
1506285345
```

TIMESTAMP VALUE:

```
2017-09-25 01:32:25
```